# Restricted selecting td elements of a table in javascript

Tags: javascript

So in this part of the script that I have I want to make it that when I select a td element, the next selection can be done only around the first one. So let's say I have the selection on variable l (for example). I want my next selection to be available only on l+n, l-n, l+1, l-1; (n is a given number by me). How can I do this? I appreciate the help. I've been brainstorming here all day but coudln't figure it out.

```
   var all = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        all[i].onclick = inputClickHandler;
    }

function inputClickHandler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var tdElm = e.target || e.srcElement;
    results = tdElm.innerHTML;
    if (tdElm.style !== null && tdElm.style.borderColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        highlighted--;
        count--;
        tdElm.style.borderColor = '#000000';
    } else if (highlighted < max) {
        highlighted++;
        count++;
        tdElm.style.borderColor = '#FF0000';

        if (count == 1) {
            selectedArr[0] = results;
        } else {
            selectedArr[1] = results;
        }
        if (count == 2) {
            sum = parseInt(selectedArr[0]) + parseInt(selectedArr[1]);
        } else {
            sum = 0;
        }
        if (count == 2) {
            var tdsElems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            if (sum == fNum) {
                max += 2;
                count = 0;
                selectedArr = [];
                score += 1;
                scoreGet.innerHTML = (score);
                for (i = 0; i < tdsElems.length; i++) {
                    if (tdsElems[i].style !== null && tdsElems[i].style.borderColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
                        tdsElems[i].style.borderColor = '#00b200';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                highlighted = 0;
                sum = 0;
                max = 2;
                selectedArr = [];
                count = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < tdsElems.length; i++) {
                    if (tdsElems[i].style !== null && tdsElems[i].style.borderColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
                        tdsElems[i].style.borderColor = '#000000';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    end_game();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @mwilson `<div id="end">

    <body>
        <h1 id="title">Pairs Game</h1>
        <button class="button" value="Refresh Page" onclick="history.go(0)">Start New Game</button>
        <p id="pairs"></p>
        <h3 id="total_pairs"></h3>
        <h3 id="score1">Score:</h3>
        <h3 id="score"></h3>
        <table align="center" id="table" class="table-spacing">
        </table>
    </body>
</div>`
  The table is made in js.

Comment: `function tableCreate() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        str += "<tr>";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            str += "<td id=\"square" + k + "\">" + "</td>";
            k++;
        }
        str += "</tr>";
    }
    table.innerHTML = str;
}`
Sorry I'm on a mac, I don't know the shortcuts to indent as code

Comment: Your javascript doesn't work. I'll just create a simple table.

Comment: ok, but it seems to work fine for me

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a simple table that leverages JavaScript and CSS to only allow a user to click on the surrounding TD's. Basically, what you want to do is add a click event to the TD's that runs some logic to calculate what is clickable (by index of current TD and row above and below). Use that to apply your CSS classes.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cv2qs6mq/2/

**HTML**

```
        <div>
            <tableid="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 4</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 4</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 4</td>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 4</td>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 4</td>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function Selector() {
    $('#myTable').find('td').click(this.onClick.bind(this));
}

Selector.prototype = {
    constructor: Selector,
    onClick: function (e) {
        var currentTd = $(e.currentTarget);
        if (currentTd.hasClass('inactive')) {
            alert('Cannot click on this td');
        } else {
            $('td').removeClass('active');
            $('td').removeClass('inactive');
            currentTd.addClass('active');
            this.highlightClickableTDs(currentTd);
            $('td').each(function (index, item) {
                if (!$(item).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(item).addClass('inactive');
                }
            });
        }
    },
    highlightClickableTDs: function (td) {
        var currentRow = td.parent();
        var previousRow = currentRow.prev();
        var nextRow = currentRow.next();
        var rowLength = currentRow.find('td').length;
        var currentTdIndex = td.index();

        if (td.next().length !== 0) {
            td.next().addClass('active');
        }

        if (td.prev().length !== 0) {
            td.prev().addClass('active');
        }

        if (previousRow.length !== 0) {
            var tdAbove = previousRow.find('td')[currentTdIndex];
            $(tdAbove).addClass('active');
        }

        if (nextRow.length !== 0) {
            var tdBelow = nextRow.find('td')[currentTdIndex];
            $(tdBelow).addClass('active');
        }

    }
}

new Selector();
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.active {
    font-style: italic;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.inactive {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```